# Getting specific portlet preferences in Liferay

Tags: java, liferay, portal

I'm using Liferay 6.1 with Struts2 and trying to get portlet preferences in the action class. My project includes 3 portlets and they all use the same action class. The class implements `PortletPreferencesAware` interface and overrides the `setPortletPreferences()` method. My question is, as all three portlets in the project have different preferences, which portlet's preferences will be returned? I don't seem to be able to get the values I want using `preferences.getValue()` in the action class.

Note, I can get the preferences in the JSP so I know they are set up correctly

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect preferences to be stored depending on the portlet that is invoked, not on the implementation class. So even if you share the implementation between 3 portlets, each will have its own set of preferences by default.

Typically the application's state will be passed into the implementation through request/response objects and its attributes and you'll have to go from there - or, preferably, through the API. Just don't expect the 3 portlets to share the same preferences out of the box, just because they share the same implementation.